# Traer clientes con mas de 3 registros y de diferencia de 2 minutos entre fecha DateTime - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo el siguiente script

```
SELECT  cl.Codigo,
    co.Cuenta,
    cl.Nombre,
    fj.CodigoTransaccion,
    fj.Monto,
    fj.FechaCreacion,


FROM dbo.Contratos co
    INNER JOIN dbo.Transacciones fj ON fj.Cuenta = co.Cuenta
    INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes cl ON cl.Codigo = co.Codigo
```

El cual me genera el siguiente resultado

```
Codigo        Cuenta    Nombre  CodigoTransaccion   Monto       Fecha Creacion
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    234               50    2022-08-29 12:47:54.623
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    235               100   2022-09-01 12:59:45.310
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    236               60    2022-09-03 13:02:40.677
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    237               80    2022-09-03 17:35:31.753
11598821    34563456    Usuario1    238               34    2022-08-22 11:28:15.853
11598787    47577472    Usuario2    239               45    2022-08-17 11:54:23.030
11598438    83756385    Usuario3    240               789   2022-08-25 17:21:17.253
11137121    62946298    Usuario4    241               342   2022-09-07 10:52:36.537
11137121    62946298    Usuario4    242               345   2022-09-07 11:02:59.727
11598216    9873615     Usuario5    243               445   2022-08-23 17:46:21.433
11601151    45254235    Usuario6    244               112   2022-08-29 17:20:05.333
11605485    432243      Usuario7    245               334   2022-08-29 17:21:05.483
11597749    432243      Usuario7    246               908   2022-08-25 17:19:17.877
11599034    432243      Usuario7    247               123   2022-08-22 11:43:18.520
```

Dichos resultados, son clientes con las transacciones que han tenido en determinado tiempo, unicamente es una muestra como tal

Lo que necesito es que del script mencionado arriba, quiero sacar solo los clientes que tengan 3 o mas registros, este es el resultado que espero

```
Codigo        Cuenta    Nombre  CodigoTransaccion   Monto       Fecha Creacion
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    234               50    2022-08-29 12:47:54.623
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    235               100   2022-09-01 12:59:45.310
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    236               60    2022-09-03 13:02:40.677
11605595    34563456    Usuario1    237               80    2022-09-03 17:35:31.753
11598821    34563456    Usuario1    238               34    2022-08-22 11:28:15.853
11605485    432243      Usuario7    245               334   2022-08-29 17:21:05.483
11597749    432243      Usuario7    246               908   2022-08-25 17:19:17.877
11599034    432243      Usuario7    247               123   2022-08-22 11:43:18.520
```

Si se fijan, los clientes "Usuario1" y "Usuario7" son los unicos que tienen 3 o mas registros

Lo otro es como puedo compara de esos clientes que tienen 3 o mas registros, la diferencia de tiempo entre cada una de ellas con la FechaCreacion, especificamente que me muestre las transacciones que tienen de diferencia 2 minutos entre ellas, asi como las primeras 2 registros del usuario7

Como puedo realizar estos 2 condiciones? si alguien me ayuda porfavor

Comment: has revisado count? quizas te pueda servir para lo que estas buscando

Comment: Exactamente ¿cuál es la salida esperada?¿Que quieres una columna adicional que te diga si la diferencia de tiempo es superior a dos minutos, o se eliminan las filas donde no se cumpla ese criterio.

Comment: count y having (con un group by) son tus amigos en este caso...

Comment: Ahi coloque el resultado que espero, es el segundo cuadro, ya intente con count y having pero sin conseguirlo

Answer (score 1):

Sobre lo que has puesto, he creado una variable tipo tabla para poner lo que tienes.

```
Set dateformat ymd;
Declare @table table (
    Codigo varchar(10),
    Cuenta varchar(10),
    Nombre varchar(10),
    CodigoTransaccion varchar(3),
    Monto int,
    FechaCreacion datetime);

Insert into @table (Codigo, Cuenta, Nombre, CodigoTransaccion,Monto, FechaCreacion)
values
('11605595','34563456','Usuario1','234',50 ,'2022-08-29 12:47:54.623'),
('11605595','34563456','Usuario1','235',100,'2022-09-01 12:59:45.310'),
('11605595','34563456','Usuario1','236',60 ,'2022-09-03 13:02:40.677'),
('11605595','34563456','Usuario1','237',80 ,'2022-09-03 17:35:31.753'),
('11598821','34563456','Usuario1','238',34 ,'2022-08-22 11:28:15.853'),
('11598787','47577472','Usuario2','239',45 ,'2022-08-17 11:54:23.030'),
('11598438','83756385','Usuario3','240',789,'2022-08-25 17:21:17.253'),
('11137121','62946298','Usuario4','241',342,'2022-09-07 10:52:36.537'),
('11137121','62946298','Usuario4','242',345,'2022-09-07 11:02:59.727'),
('11598216','9873615' ,'Usuario5','243',445,'2022-08-23 17:46:21.433'),
('11601151','45254235','Usuario6','244',112,'2022-08-29 17:20:05.333'),
('11605485','432243'  ,'Usuario7','245',334,'2022-08-29 17:21:05.483'),
('11597749','432243'  ,'Usuario7','246',908,'2022-08-25 17:19:17.877'),
('11599034','432243'  ,'Usuario7','247',123,'2022-08-22 11:43:18.520');

With source as
    (
    Select COUNT(1) as veces, t.Nombre
        From @table t
    group by t.Nombre
    having COUNT(1)>=2
)
select t.* 
    from source inner join @table t
    on source.Nombre= t.Nombre;
```

[image: Res1]

Qué podrías escribir en tú código, algo así:

```
With source as
    (
    SELECT COUNT(1) As veces, cl.Nombre
    FROM dbo.Contratos co
        INNER JOIN dbo.Transacciones fj ON fj.Cuenta = co.Cuenta
        INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes cl ON cl.Codigo = co.Codigo
    group by cl.Nombre
    having COUNT(1)>=3
), data as (
    SELECT  cl.Codigo,
        co.Cuenta,
        cl.Nombre,
        fj.CodigoTransaccion,
        fj.Monto,
        fj.FechaCreacion,
    FROM dbo.Contratos co
        INNER JOIN dbo.Transacciones fj ON fj.Cuenta = co.Cuenta
        INNER JOIN dbo.Clientes cl ON cl.Codigo = co.Codigo
)select data.* 
    from source inner join data 
    on source.Nombre= data.Nombre;
```